# Entity Framework ObjectMaterialized for Anonymous Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

`ObjectMaterialized` is only called when the the created object is an actual class, or maybe it has a mapping for it; not sure which.

If I use an anonymous object, the `ObjectMaterialized` delegate is never called.

```
var obj = context.Set<MyType>().Select( x =>
{
    Prop = x.Prop1,
});
```

Is there a way to get the `ObjectMaterialized` delegate to be called with an anonymous type?

Currently I'm doing a workaround where I call `.ToList()` on the query before I select the anonymous type to ensure it gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doesn't look like it- from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Occurs when a new entity object is created from data in the data
>   source as part of a query or load operation.
>
> This event is raised after all scalar, complex, and reference
>   properties have been set on an object, but before collections are
>   loaded. If an object with the same key value exists in the object
>   context, the Entity Framework will not recreate the object and this
>   event will not be raised.

looks like you won't be able to call the event handler directly either- the ObjectMaterializedEventArgs constructor is declared internal :(